# Setting Minimum Date to a textbox type=date based on a value in another textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, textbox

I have a `textbox` which has a type `date` and I want to compare the selected date to the value of a textbox in my ASP.NET page

See image below

[image]

ASP.NET Code: (for Date Textbox)

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label11" 
    Font-Bold="True"> Date Received:</asp:Label>&nbsp;
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDate" 
    Width="150px" type="date" Height="31px" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Code Behind:

```
txtDate.Attributes.Add("min", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

I was able to make the previous dates unselectable but I want  to compare the date selected at the Final Delivery Date.

I just don't know how.

Please help. Thank you in advance. Still new to ASP.NET and C#.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this using Asp.Net's compare validator.

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="cmpVal1" ControlToCompare="txtFinalDeliveryDate" 
     ControlToValidate="txtDate" Type="Date" Operator="LessThanEqual"   
     ErrorMessage="Date should be less than final delivery date"
     runat="server"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

This will show the error message if user enters a date greater than the final delivery date.

This will work only if both controls are input controls. If you need to compare with a label, then you can use the ValueToCompare property instead of ControlToCompare. ValueToCompare can be set from code behind

Comment: I did not get any error the page doesn't view when i put that code to compare `txtDate` and `txtFinalDeliveryDate`. wait i am going to try it again. I thing i am comparing the wrong Label/TextBox name

Comment: Thus, for all i know you can't compare label and textbox huhuhu

Comment: Ohh.. Did not realise that final delivery date was a label. In that case you should use ValueToCompare property instead of ControlToCompare. You could set this while setting the label.

Comment: Updated the same in the answer